# Storing base and derived class in a single list

Tags: c#, oop, polymorphism

I'm doing a foundation uni C# assignment and could use a little help. We're making a pizza application and are required to have the pizza sauces (3 kinds) as a `Sauce` class derived from `Ingredient`. So I have a class `Ingredient` and a derived class `Sauce`.

I'm storing the ingredients in a list which then gets iterated through to pull out the cost of ingredients and whatnot. Naturally the `Sauce` object has methods of the same name that do things differently (overrides?) My trouble is that the `Sauce` objects are not returning the correct values.

I set a break point immediately following initialising the list. As you can see here: http://i.imgur.com/BgwKeWL.png it seems that the information is being doubled up in the list for some reason. This is the code that loads the data into the list:

```
ingredients.Add(new Ingredient("Mushrooms", 0.75, 80, "handfuls"));
ingredients.Add(new Sauce("Tomato Sauce", "cups"));
```

Presumably the later methods are returning invalid values because they're returning the first of each value it finds.

Which brings me to... what's the best way to store both `Ingredient` and the derived `Sauce` in the same list, such that I iterate through the list using a single method call and it will use the base or derived class's method as appropriate?

Comment: You would have to show us how `Ingredient` and `Sauce` are defined.

Comment: When resolving a call to a virtual method, the .NET runtime will look at the runtime-type of an object, so this comes down to how your classes are designed. Did you perhaps forget the `override` keyword in the Sauce-class, thereby "hiding" the parents method? This would probably result in the behavior you're describing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've duplicated the fields and properties in the derived class, so you have something like this:

```
class Ingredient {
    Ingredient(decimal cost) { Cost = cost; }
    public double Cost { get; set; }
}

class Sauce : Ingredient {
    Sauce(decimal cost) { Cost = cost; }
    // This hides Ingredient.Cost.
    // You probably don't want that.
    public double Cost { get; set; }
}
```

The constructor for `Sauce` sets `Sauce.Cost`, but when accessed through a `List<Ingredient>`, `Ingredient.Cost` is accessed.

Remove the duplicated fields in the derived class.

Oh, and use `decimal` for money, rather than `double`.

Comment: Also, pay notice to the compile-time warning. If the C# compiler said the member `Cost` of `Sauce` ***hides*** the other member `Cost` that `Sauce` inherited from its base class, that is a sign something is wrong. Do not use the `new` keyword to make the warning go away. Instead, either remove the "extra" member from the derived class (`Sauce`), or, if you need both members, choose another name for the new member that does not conflict with the names inherited from the base class. Of course, if you want to specialize the behavior of an inherited member, use `virtual` on base, and `override`.

Comment: I had indeed done that. Having removed those, I'm no longer getting the dupes.

Interestingly, the compiler didn't offer any warnings that I was hiding or duplicating fields.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short sample for what you want on your methods :

```
class Ingredient
{
    public int Nom;

    public virtual void TellName()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ingredient");
    }
}

class Sauce : Ingredient
{
    public override void TellName()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Sauce");
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var ingredientList = new List<Ingredient> {new Ingredient(), new Sauce()};

        foreach (var ingredient in ingredientList)
        {
            ingredient.TellName();
        }
    }
}
```

Output :

Ingredient

Sauce